# JavaScript Rounding Calculated Field to Two Decimal Places

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, rounding

I saw a few rounding examples but i can't figure out how to code mine, here is what I have. I need to round the val to two decimal places, this is a dollar value.

I looked at other posts with similar question but i can't figure it out on my own code, any help is appreciated!

```
$(function() {
$("#bpComputers").change(function() {
    var suPrice = 19.99;
    var value=$(this).val();

    if(value === "---") { $("#amountInDollars").val("Select a Number"); }
    if(value === "1") { $("#amountInDollars").val(1 * suPrice); }
    if(value === "2") { $("#amountInDollars").val(2 * suPrice); } 
    if(value === "3") { $("#amountInDollars").val(3 * suPrice); }
    if(value === "4") { $("#amountInDollars").val(4 * suPrice); }
});
});
```

Found a solution to my issue...

```
$(function() {
    $("#bpComputers").change(function() {
        //Define Sign Up and Setup Fee Costs
        var suPrice = 19.99;
        var suSetupFee = 0.00;

        //Define and Calculate Computer Costs
        var onePC = 1 * suPrice;
        var twoPCs = 2 * suPrice;
        var threePCs = 3 * suPrice;
        var fourPCs = 4 * suPrice;

        //Define a Selector and Value for costPerPC
        var value = $(this).val();

        //Populate costPerPC Based on Computers Selected
        if(value === "---") { $("input[name='costPerPC']").val("0.00"); }
        if(value === "1") { $("input[name='costPerPC']").val(onePC.toFixed(2)); }
        if(value === "2") { $("input[name='costPerPC']").val(twoPCs.toFixed(2)); }
        if(value === "3") { $("input[name='costPerPC']").val(threePCs.toFixed(2)); }
        if(value === "4") { $("input[name='costPerPC']").val(fourPCs.toFixed(2)); }
    });
});
```

Comment: I saw that post and couldn't figure it out with my code. Thanks though.

Comment: @31piy I was able to solve my own question with little help from the duplicate mark you made. I will edit with the solution.